# mysql insert auto increments but does not insert row

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I need guidance on something that is confusing me. I have a mysql insert query that works like 99% of the time but in some few cases, the auto increment field updates but the row is not inserted. The query is as below:

```
$result = mysql_query("insert into receipts 
  values('','".$rcptno."','".$cid."','".$names."','".$stream."','".$pname."',
  '".$fintot."','cr','".date('Y/m/d')."','".date('Ymd')."','1','".$username."','".
  $sess."','".$refno."','".$prevbal."','".$newbal."')");
```

When I try inserting the same data again, it inserts perfectly. I would just like to know what might be causing this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's normal. `auto_increment` gets incremented even if the actual record doesn't make it to the disk. This behavior has to be like this, otherwise MySQL wouldn't be able to guarantee safe concurrent access. If you want to know what went wrong (it's usually deadlock in question) - use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` and read the lengthy message to see what caused MySQL to refuse to write data to disk. When that happens, the usual approach is to re-try the transaction.

Comment: learnt something new - SHOW ENGINE INNODB . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The id is always incremented. But in case the insertion fails because of some trigger or the transaction is rolled back, the autoincremented value is not reused.